# What is the purpose of HandlerExtensions.ConnectHandle ConnectHandler<T>() method?

Tags: masstransit

Xmldoc states:

> Adds a message handler to the service bus for handling a specific type
>   of message

But it does not require endpoint name. How then does it work? I tried this method, but nothing happened.

Is there any possibility to add handlers dynamically, while bus is running?

Comment: Full-blown handlers are analysed at bus start up and MT creates the necessary infrastructure elements like topics and exchanges to support subscriptions. This only happens when the bus starts.

Answer (score 1):

By connecting a handler to the bus after it has been started, messages can be sent to the bus's address directly. This is particularly useful for things like responses to requests, which should not be published and are sent immediately back to the endpoint.

When using `bus.ConnectHandler(context => {...})` to add a handler to the bus dynamically, no subscriptions or exchange bindings are created on the broker. It's only possible to receive messages which are directly sent to the endpoint.

When a message is sent from the bus, such as a request, the `SourceAddress` is added to the message header. If a request is sent, the `ResponseAddress` is also set. A fault address can also be specified if you want to use a non-dynamic endpoint to capture faults (such as a failed command that is not awaited, IE, fire and forget) so that faults can be triaged and handled appropriately by another persistent endpoint.